# Cannot scroll horizontally when using a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a `UIViewController` to which I have added a `UIScrollView` with `top, bottom, leading and trailing` constraints set to 0 to nearest neighbour (which is `self.view`).

To this I have added a `UIView` (content view), also with top, bottom, leading and trailing set to 0 to nearest neighbour (the `UIScrollView`), and align center X and Y.

Inside the content view I have added a `UIImageView` with constraints: Align center X to content view, bottom and top space is 0 to nearest neighbour (the content view), and a 10:3 ratio. **All of this is done in Storyboard using auto layout!**

So now the `UIImageView` is much wider than `self.view`. I have a hard time understanding exactly how the `UIScrollView` works in storyboard, so I don't get why I cannot scroll horizontally now that the `UIImageView` is much wider than `self.view`.

Can anyone explain it and maybe help me with my problem? Any thoughts will be greatly appreacheated! And if my explanation is unclear or confusing, please tell me and I'll try to rewrite it.

#### Edit: My constraints

An overview of the view hierarchy:
[image]

Scroll View:
[image]

ContentView: 
[image]

ImageView:
[image]

Comment: you have to set contentSize of scroll view according to your need

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried setting `self.scrollView.contentSize` but is has no effect :-/

Comment: why you add a contentview in scrollview, direct add a image view and set constraint according to scrollview not to the main view. or you may add autolayout constraint.

Comment: please share your code, if you can.

Comment: @Subhash Sharma - I have just added my screenshots of my constraints. So far there's no code, only storyboard.

Comment: can you please remove content view and then try directly on imageview

Comment: That produces the storyboard error: "Scroll View has ambiguous scrollable content width".

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand autolayout cannot calculate the contentSize of your UIScrollView. The view (content view) that you added seems to be the exact same size as the UIScrollView so this means the scrollview contentsize is equal to his frame size which basically means no scrolling.

Try to test first with a fixed width constraint or the content view then move on and add more complex constraints.

The trick is that you have to give the scrollview via autolayout enough constraint that he will be able to calculate the contentsize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried to set the contentView's leading and trailing to -400, but it did not make any difference :-/

Comment: First, add a width and height constraint to your Content View. From your screenshots I see you dont have these constraints added so thats most likely the root of the problem.

Comment: But I cannot have a fixed width and height because it needs to support all screen sizes.